# remove unwanted social sharing options from the list in SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Tags: cordova

I am using social sharing cordova plugin to share something. It works fine but I want only Twitter, Facebook, SMS and Whatsapp options in the list.

Now it look like this

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I see on the docs (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin), the list of things to share is based on system settings, so you can't modify that list. Except for iOS apparently where you can. But since your screen shot is Android, I don't think you can modify this.

You can share to a particular service, so if you want to build your own UI, you could share *just* for Twitter and FB for example, but then you have to handle the UI.

Comment: Okay fine. Thank you